# Overwriting property when I'm filling my complex property List<Object>

Tags: c#

I'm having problems on filling my object property which is a List . Below I'll be able to show you better the problem.

```
Grupo grupo = null;
SubGrupo subGrupo = null;

if (Regex.IsMatch(linhaTrim, @"\b(?<!\.)([A-Z]{1,})(?!\.)\b"))
{
    grupo = new Grupo(Convert.ToInt32(arraySplit[arraySplit.Length - 1]), grupoTextoTrim);
    if (grupoTextoTrim.Equals("DISPONIBILIDADE DE DOCUMENTOS OFICIAIS"))
    {
        grupo.ler = false;
        indice.Add(grupo);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        grupo.ler = true;
    }

    grupo.SubGrupos = new List<SubGrupo>();
    indice.Add(grupo);
}
else
{
    //aqui será feita a verificação se existe ou não no indice um determinado subgrupo
    //subGrupo = new SubGrupo(Convert.ToInt32(arraySplit[arraySplit.Length - 1]), grupoTexto.Trim());
    subGrupo = new SubGrupo();
    subGrupo = subGrupos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.descricao.Equals(grupoTextoTrim));
    subGrupo.pagina = Convert.ToInt32(arraySplit[arraySplit.Length - 1]);
    grupo.SubGrupos.Insert(grupo.SubGrupos.Count, subGrupo);
}
```

The problem is at this line : 
`subGrupo.pagina = Convert.ToInt32(arraySplit[arraySplit.Length - 1]);`

At my loop , there are some identical references at descricao property and the difference between those identical references is the property page at SubGrupo object .

After the loop , when I check my List I should have something like this :

```
Grupo 
   descricao : x
   SubGrupo : 
        descricao : y
        pagina : y
   End SubGrupo
End Grupo

Grupo 
   descricao : x
   SubGrupo : 
        descricao : y
        pagina : z
   End SubGrupo
End Grupo
```

But now is returning the same value for pagina .

Does anyone can help me ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: your `subGrupo.pagina` will always return the same value (the last value in `arraySplit`) unless you're adding to it in some other code that's not posted. Should you be retrieving a different value for this in the array?

Comment: Pls look at the comment that I made for CK below . I think that solved my problem . I'm adding the subGrupo.pagina in each iteration to get another object when I do the FirstOrDefault . If you have any concerns about it , pls tell me ok ? Tks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you share looping logic implemented. But based on logic you posted issue seems to be possible at two places:

1. If `arraySplit` (array of integers) initializes outside loop and you
   are not removing elements from the array,
   `arraySplit[arraySplit.Length - 1]` will always return same value.

   E.g. `int[] arraySplit = {1,2,3,4};`

   `arraySplit[arraySplit.Length - 1]  = 4` always.
2. If `grupoTextoTrim` initialize outside loop, or initialize with same value in each iteration, copy of same object will be added to list:
   `subGrupo = subGrupos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.descricao.Equals(grupoTextoTrim));`

Comment: CK , both variables are intialized inside of the loop , but I found the problem . When I do the FirstOrDefault , I was setting the pagina property and after that , when I do this again in the future searching for the same value , knowing that I can have the same value repated , I was rewritting the same property with another value . Now I'm setting it to not catch the same object at my List . But if you have any other concerns about what I said , pls , let me know .